# Steam crashes on startup on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, steam

I've googled and tried all the fixes I came across but i'm still unable to launch steam.

Here is the output when i run `steam` from the command line:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 18.04 64-bit STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically Pins up-to-date! Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1566431379) libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1566431379) Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1566431379) Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail" Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"

(steam:22743): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita", /usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/main.rc:733: error: unexpected identifier direction', expected character}'

(steam:22743): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita", /usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/hacks.rc:28: error: invalid string constant "normal_entry", expected valid string constant libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast Steam: An X Error occurred X Error of failed request: GLXBadContext Major opcode of failed request: 154 Serial number of failed request: 49 xerror_handler: X failed, continuing Steam: An X Error occurred X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation) Major opcode of failed request: 154 Value in failed request: 0x0 Serial number of failed request: 48 xerror_handler: X failed, continuing Steam: An X Error occurred X Error of failed request: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) Major opcode of failed request: 154 Serial number of failed request: 50 xerror_handler: X failed, continuing crash_20190910205216_1.dmp[22768]: Uploading dump (out-of-process) /tmp/dumps/crash_20190910205216_1.dmp /home/scdigital/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 720: 22743 Segmentation fault (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@" crash_20190910205216_1.dmp[22768]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes crash_20190910205216_1.dmp[22768]: response: CrashID=bp-184ef0d9-7f14-48a7-8f3c-377932190910 crash_20190910205216_1.dmp[22768]: file ''/tmp/dumps/crash_20190910205216_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-184ef0d9-7f14-48a7-8f3c-377932190910''
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems the 32bit OpenGL driver isn't installed. Try to run `flatpak update`

Comment: I don't have flatpak installed. do i need it to update the 32bit open GL driver?

Comment: Thank you abu-ahmed al-khatiri, I did some more googling based on your comment and resolved the issue. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like I found the issue. Thanks to abu-ahmed al-khatiri for pointing me in the right direction.

I had to install the following package:

sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-410:i386

But changed 410 to 430 which is my current driver version.

Steam started up and I was able to login.

thank you guys!

Comment: Well steam runs, but no games do... linux, the future of gaming... lol ya right